# strtok fails despite it proper invocation

Tags: c, strtok

What is the issue with below code fragment; it fails at line#25. I am not understanding why is it failing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char linebuf[1024]="SET SLMSRVR 10.133.2.102:    50011";
char *tempStr;
char *str;

int main()
{
    tempStr = calloc(1024, sizeof(char));

    strcpy(tempStr, linebuf+strlen("SET SLMSRVR"));
    printf("1 tempStr: %s\r\n", tempStr);

    str = strtok(tempStr, ":");
    printf("2 tempStr: %s\tstr: %s\r\n", tempStr, str);

    if (str != NULL){
        printf("Server IP: %s\r\n",str);
    } else {
        printf("Error 1\r\n");
    }

    str = strtok(tempStr, NULL);
    printf("3 tempStr: %s\tstr: %s\r\n", tempStr, str);
    if (str != NULL) {
        printf("Port: %s\r\n", str);
   } 

    return 0;
}
```

Here as the specification of strtok suggests, first it is called with delimiter string and then with `NULL`, first argument in both cases the string to be parsed. It fails parsing for the second time.

Any thoughts?

Comment: And we're supposed to count line #25?

Answer (score 2):

The second time you should call it as str = strtok(NULL, ":");

Answer (score 2):

I believe you got it wrong. A call like

```
  str = strtok(tempStr, NULL);
```

does not make sense, you're passing the pointer to delimiter string as a `NULL`. If you want to continue parsing the same string as before, you need to pass the first argument as `NULL`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.24.5.8, (*emphasis mine*)

> ```
> char *strtok(char * restrict s1,
> ```
>
> const char * restrict s2);
>
> A sequence of calls to the `strtok()` function breaks the string pointed to by `s1` into a
>   sequence of tokens, each of which is delimited by a character from the string pointed to
>   by `s2`. **The first call in the sequence has a non-null first argument; subsequent calls in the
>   sequence have a null first argument.** The separator string pointed to by `s2` may be
>   different from call to call.

Maybe what you want is

```
 str = strtok(NULL, ":");  //or some other delimiter
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Just got it.